# How to draw diagram like this one (errorsbar)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to draw a graph that looks like this one from:

[image]

The closest I have come is this graph:

[image]

by this code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_fname)
df['cluster'] = [3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1]

def mean_plus_std(x): return np.mean(x) + np.std(x)
def mean_minus_std(x): return np.mean(x) - np.std(x)

dfeb = df.drop(columns=['COUNTY_NAME', 'PARTY_NAME']).groupby('cluster').agg([np.mean, mean_minus_std ,mean_plus_std])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
sns.catplot(data=dfeb.reset_index().melt(id_vars='cluster'), x='variable_0', y='value', hue='cluster', ax=ax)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(),rotation=30, ha='right');
```

Data (csv) are from https://exploratory.io/data/kanaugust/2016-California-Election-Data-oTv4Hgd1UT

Output looks like this:

[image]

So for each column graph should present mean - std, mean, mean + std.
These three values should be drawn as three dots connected with line for each column.
Does someone have a clue how to do it in python by using matplotlib/seaborn?

EDIT 1:

How to draw errors bar for each ("Adult Film Condom Requirements" and "Ban on Single-use Plastic Bags") column if I know column's means and standard deviations with cluster as hue as it is presented in the first picture in this question?

[image]

Comment: Check out [pyplot.errorbar](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html)

Comment: Thank you for errorbar suggestion. Now I understand how can I use it when I have x, y and yerr, but in my case x should be column (level 0) name, y should be mean (for each cluster) and yerr should be std (for each cluster).
I have just edited the question with EDIT 1 section.
I don't know how to do it.